# Mozilla Firefox Add-on not working while a new window is opened on clicking anchor

Tags: firefox, tabs, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am developing a Firefox add-on using Add-on SDK tool. I am doing something as soon as a tab is opened. I registered for all tab's event( open,ready,close).

```
    var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");

    tabs.on("open",openTab);
    tabs.on("ready",readyTab);
    tabs.on("close",closeTab);
```

And i have respective functions for each event Listener. ***Problem which i am facing is some of the webpages opened in a new window. For those web pages none of the event Listener is firing. Help me out in this.***

The page is triggering tabs.on("open") while i am closing the window.

Answer (score 0):

The [tabs API documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs) says:

> The module itself can be used as a list of all opened tabs across all windows.

The tabs listeners are supposed to work on all tabs across all browser windows. Maybe something in the listener functions (openTab, closeTab etc) is causing the problem?